# how to update the UI when binding datagrid to nested objects in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding

I'm early days learning how to build a UI using PowerShell and WPF, and I'm stumped on how to connect an object to a DataGrid so that the UI automatically updates when items in the object change.

This is the WPF:

```
$Xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="800" Height="300" Name="khsdeflpnonyb">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="updateButton"/>
      <Button Content="Update Async" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="updateButtonASync"/>
      <Button Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="refreshButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="observableDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="6" ItemsSource="{Binding serverList}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedServer}">
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

I am using an 'observable' collection as the type, which i'm creating during the window OnLoad:

```
function OnLoad
{
    $results = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[System.Object]'
    
    $results.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
               "ServerInstance" = "MyServer"
               "targetAccount" = "svcAccount"
               "isEverythingDone"  = $false
               "Status" = ""                
    })
    
    $observableDataGrid.itemsSource = $results  
}
```

On pressing the "Update" button, i'm expecting the status to update in the UI:

```
function UpdateButton
{
    # $State is the Data Context.
    # selectedServer is bound to the observable DataGrid "selectedItem" property.
    $State.selectedServer.Status = (Get-Random | Out-String)

    # If I uncomment the following line it works
    #$observableDataGrid.Items.Refresh()

    # However, I understand it should be possible to change objects
    # inside the "state" (Data Context - $State - the model) without calling 
    # Refresh and have them reflected in the UI (the 'view').  
    # This latter approach is preferred as I  think this should then also work 
    # using PoshGUI's Async method.

}

function UpdateButtonAsync
{
    Async {
    $State.selectedServer.Status = (Get-Random | Out-String)
    }
}
```

(The 'Async' function is from https://poshgui.com)

I can force the datagrid to update using the code below, but this isn't helpful in the asynchonous case because in poshgui this runspace only has access to the state and datacontext.

```
function Refresh
{
    $observableDataGrid.Items.Refresh()
}
```

I also understand forcing a refresh is the 'wrong' way to do it.

I think the issue may be that PSCustomObject does not implement the iNotifyPropertyChanged interface, if that is the case can someone help guide how this might be done?

The full code is available on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kewalaka/0dea5e546d7cbff3a6b8e6b1cc753e0a).

**Edit**: an update that attempts to implement the INotifyPropertyChange interface is available on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kewalaka/08bb9d0ee35ecbf0454827008ecafd11), unfortunately this still does not allow me to update the model (DataContext) and have it reflect in the view (the grid).

Comment: It's UX/UI form events the react to change, not PowerShell code. There must be code assigned to the event when it is triggered. Your UX/UI shoudl work regardless of the code behind the language you use for other logic. Your code-behind should just work, regardless of the UX/UI it is targeted for. Data grids have been in UX/UI for decades well before PowerShell ever existed. So, [search for the event need use case](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27wpf+refresh+datagrid%27&t=h_&ia=web), not PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks - I have already made the change using examples from the link provided (e.g. using an 'observable' collection, and manually calling refresh).  What I'm asking is how changes to the nested object can be reflected up the UI without simply adding or removing items from the parent collection.  i.e. where does this code sit - do I need to implement a class and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface instead of using a PSCustomObject?  It's probably obvious to a .net developer but not to me.

Comment: Had a go writing a class and implementing that interface, it still isn't updating until 'refresh' is called,still missing something.  Gist with full source: https://gist.github.com/kewalaka/08bb9d0ee35ecbf0454827008ecafd11

Comment: FYI... There is also always the option that you populate datagrid on page load, and set a timer to tick every X seconds; thus when the timer ticks, it will call a method to load data to the grid again. Yet that is not as dynamic as the *change events. Btw, PowerShell is a gateway drug to becoming a .Net (C#) developer, especially when you start do UX/UI as you r trying. Just say'in. Also, quck look at your second version, you are showing *chage stuff. So, I'll look more when I can. Right now, it's late and well, u'know. ;-}, old dudes need their beauty sleep.  ;'-}

Comment: I was just looking over your original. I'll grab this one as well. Yet, in your current one, the data table is not editable at all, so, I'd expect the update to fail. You have no 'change' events (NewRow, RowChanged, SelectionChnaged, CellChanged, UpdateSourceTrigger, etc.) in your code, hence the reason for having to do this '$observableDataGrid.Items.Refresh()'. Not that the latter is really a bad thing. Relative t your 'I also understand forcing a refresh is the 'wrong' way to do it.', and I've never seen a write-up that this is not valid. It's common practice in most code I review.

Comment: thanks :)  yes it works - i guess I'd stick with it, but I want to call some async code to do a bunch of things, and at the stage the only way i can think to keep the grid up to date is to use a timer in the main body of code like you suggest - FYI i was going to use a dispatch timer.  

```
$TimerCode = {
# Code here
}
$DispatcherTimer = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
$DispatcherTimer.Interval = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(10)
$DispatcherTimer.Add_Tick($TimerCode)
$DispatcherTimer.Start()
```

Comment: what i want to be able to do is to update the 'model' which is the state / datacontext, and have it reflect in the 'view' - the datagrid, I know it's the 'right' way, but my .net foo fails me :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224916/discussion-between-stu-and-postanote).

Comment: Well, I was just about to shut down, and yep, we can chat tomorrow. But in the mean time, I pulled up some old code, to check something, so, play with doing stuff like... this: [$DataGrid1.ItemsSource  = $Datatable.DefaultView] in your event call. I'll show what I mean tomorrow in the chat.